Representation of finite fields as matrices
How a prime-ordered finite field $F_p$ can be represented as a matrix field? I found many claims that this is possible online but all the links are either paywalled or non-functional (as in this answer, for instance).

Did you look up the referenced article "Matrix Representation of Finite Fields" by William P. Wardlaw (https://doi.org/10.2307/2690850 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690850)?

@SamHopkins it is paywalled.

@SamHopkins done, thanks very much. I sent you a e-mail to which you can reply.
